# Help figuring out how to create a page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I am using **Magento 1.9**. Let's just say the documentation and community support is extremely lacking. I have spent the last week trying to figure out how to make a simple **static HTML page** for the **admin area** of Magento. Between incomplete tutorials and outdated documentation, it's a nightmare.

I BELIEVE I am at a point now where the admin page is actually loading, but it's blank so I can't tell. I guess now I am trying to figure out how to tell the system to use the layout for this page. (Again, it's going to be a static HTML page with a paragraph of text and an embedded YouTube video).

Let's get to the work here:
This is my `config.xml`: - UPDATED

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Cen_Tutorial>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Cen_Tutorial>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <cen_tutorial>
        <class>Cen_Tutorial_Helper</class>
      </cen_tutorial>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <layout>
    <updates>
      <tutorial>
        <file>pdftutorial.xml</file>
      </tutorial>
    </updates>
  </layout>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <Cen_Tutorial after="Mage_Adminhtml">Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml</Cen_Tutorial>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

And this is my `adminhtml.xml`: - UPDATED

```
<config>
  <menu>
    <cen translate="title" module="cen_tutorial">
      <title>PDF Tutorial</title>
      <sort_order>99</sort_order>
      <action>adminhtml/cen_tutorial/index</action>
    </cen>
  </menu>
</config>
```

This is my `TutorialController.php`: - UPDATED

Now in `/app/code/community/Cen/Tutorial/controllers/Adminhtml/Cen/TutorialController.php`:

```
<?php

class Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml_Cen_TutorialController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

This is the contents of my `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/pdftutorial.xml`:

```
<layout>
  <adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index>
    <update handle="adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index" />
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="adminhtml/template" name="tutorial" template="cen/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index>
</layout>
```

And finally, the contents of my `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cen/index.phtml`:

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello, world!';
?>
```

This entire system and structure seems completely complicated, not well documented, and difficult to do anything with, even something as simple as creating one single use-page. What seems to be the problem with what I've pasted? I am on Magento 1.9.

I forgot to include my Helper class but it's in the source.

Comment: firstly you have error in your xml befor not after in this line <Cen_Tutorial after="Mage_Adminhtml">Cen_Tutorial</Cen_Tutorial>

Comment: and <layout> will be under <config><adminhtml> directly not <config><admin><adminhtml>

Answer (score 0):

With few adjustments I was able to get your template to render:

**Step1:**

Let`s start with controller.
Your definition is not up to the standards and this is how it should look:

```
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Cen_Tutorial before="Mage_Adminhtml">Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml</Cen_Tutorial>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

the difference is

- since one of the patches we keep all our admin controller in folder `controllers/Adminhtml` thus the class path `Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml`
- Additionally you may want to consider moving your controllers in subfolder, i.e. Cen so that this one would become `controllers/Adminhtml/Cen/TutorialController.php`
- That is because controller class/path relative to the module will **set its url**
- i.e if you were to create ProductController.php for some reason - it will collide with core ProductController and **something entirely unrelated will be broken**
- So it is better to use namespaces (folders with the name of vendor/module) for controllers

**Step2:**

Layout then.
In global `<config>` there are several nodes that can be used. Some of them are:

- admin
- frontend
- adminhtml
- global (note that `adminhtml` will be in the same level `global` is)

in this case - because we want our template in admin area - we will want to use adminhtml node so the config becomes:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Cen_Tutorial>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Cen_Tutorial>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <cen_tutorial>
            <class>Cen_Tutorial_Helper</class>
        </cen_tutorial>
    </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <tutorial>
                <file>pdftutorial.xml</file>
            </tutorial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Cen_Tutorial after="Mage_Adminhtml">Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml</Cen_Tutorial>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

And we place our file in appropriate path, like app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/pdftutorial.xml

**Step3:**

Layout

In this particular case and naming we have - the layout is correct, but here are some things to note:

- `update` handle does nothing, unless there is some `tutorial_tutorial_index` somehwere. If that's the case - you will `inherit` all its contents
- layout handle `adminhtml_tutorial_index` is created from controller path. in this case (admin area) the first part is adminhtml, second part is full controller path (relative to the `Adminhtml` folder) and the 3 part is controller action
- So if you were to move your controller into `Adminhtml/Cen/TutorialController` - layout handle would be: `<adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index>` and also all paths would become the same (i.e `<action>adminhtml/cen_tutorial/index</action>`)

So after applying some changes:
[image]

Hope I was able to help and this made some sense.

Comment: I am trying to keep up with your comment, but I can't quite see what is different. In attempting to change config.xml it looks exactly like the one you pasted. Aside from moving the controller into controllers/Adminhtml/TutorialController.php, I don't see anything else that's different from what I have in my source.

Comment: Yours is inside <admin> node but mine is one level higher. Inside <config>. Will add whole config.xml in a minute.

Comment: Hmm, now I am getting an error on the page when accessing it, except I have error display disabled so I cant see what it is. Controller file was loaded, but class does not exist

Comment: Okay, so then it is report. One checks what is written there with cat var/report/#number or copying errors/local.xml{.sample,}

Comment: Yeah, the error is 'Controller file was loaded but class does not exist', This started after I moved TutorialController to /controllers/Adminhtml/Cen/TutorialController.php

Comment: <config>
    <menu>
 <cen translate="title" module="cen_tutorial">
            <title>PDF Tutorial</title>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/cen_tutorial/index</action>
        </cen>
    </menu>
</config>

Comment: In magento class names are derived from path. With this path correct class name would be: Cen_Tutorial_Adminhtml_Cen_TutorialController

Where Cen_Tutorial - module name
Adminhtml_Cen - folders relative to module root
TutorialController - file (class) name

Comment: Yep, I just changed that however I am back again now to just a blank screen with no rendered content. It SHOULD be rendering an h1 tag with 'Hello, World!' in it, but it's just a blank screen again.

Comment: I updated the question to match the most recent version of all the files

Comment: just remove <update> tag from pdftutorial.xml file and add closing </layout> tag ther and you should be good to go.

in this case you are trying to merge the handle <adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index> into itself which ends up in infinite loop.
also do not forget to clean caches.

Comment: <layout>
  <adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="adminhtml/template" name="tutorial" template="cen/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_cen_tutorial_index>
</layout>
 ?

Comment: I GOT IT! Thank you for your help! I can't believe what I had to go through to make a single page with a paragraph on it.